# Difference between nbreg in Stata and glm.nb in R?

Tags: r, regression, negative-binomial-distribution

I am reviewing someone else's statistical analysis that they did in Stata.  I noted that they ran a negative binomial regression using "nbreg", and the output looks like this:

Fitting Poisson model:
Iteration 0:   log likelihood =  -1231.867
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -1141.8667

Fitting constant-only model:
Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -1204.0909
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -986.85215
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -985.85009
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -985.85009

Fitting full model:
Iteration 0:    log likelihood = -989.34782
Iteration 1:    log likelihood = -988.09229
Iteration 2:    log likelihood = -978.05645
Iteration 3:    log likelihood = -978.05644

Then, it displays the regression results.

I thought that if I just run a negative binomial regression in R, I could get the same output, so I used "glm.nb" with the same variables.  The output is close, but not the same.  I'm wondering if anyone knows what the difference is with the defaults, or if there is a way to retrieve the negative binomial regression results I received from Stata in R?

Here are the coefficients and standard errors from each:

[image: stata vs r]

Comment: *Specifically* what differs between the two results and by *exactly* how much?

Comment: all the coefficients, t-stats, p-values....they're off by a little which makes me think the functions aren't doing the same calculation?

Comment: Please tell us exactly how much is a "little"!  Especially when estimates are made with numerical procedures, you should *expect* minor differences that are within (a) the standard errors of estimates and (b) the tolerances of the procedures.  Until you disclose this crucial information, we can do little more than guess what you might be referring to.

Comment: "Stata" is so spelled: http://www.statalist.org/forums/help#spelling

Comment: Why are there edits of "STATA" to "Stata".  This seems entirely irrelevant to the questions asked.  Regardless of what someone's preference is, the logo is written as STaTa.  I think that should be more technically correct no?

Comment: Thank you for posting the information.  Apparently the two programs are converging on the same solution.  You might find it interesting and useful to get them to report the likelihoods that are associated with their solutions: the one with the larger likelihood is probably closer to being correct.  It would not be surprising to find that these two solutions produce identical likelihoods to many decimal places (perhaps six or more).

Comment: Stata:  Log likelihood = -978.05644; r:  2 x log-likelihood:  -1956.0750

Comment: Is there any way to get them to converge or get the same results by adding code?

Comment: Those values are not comparable because one (or both) of the programs ignores constant terms in the log likelihood and/or applies a constant factor. (I suspect one of them is twice the other.) To get a legitimate comparison, you can input the coefficients from one of the programs into the other and ask it for the likelihood. Regardless, differences (in the true likelihood) less than $1.92$ are usually considered insignificant--and here the difference is only one-hundredth that: we're surely looking at differences in the numerical methods used. The docs tell you how to increase the precision.

Comment: Rolled back to *Stata*; the appearance of the logo is not the official name of the product.